# Avatar distorted at certain sizes

Tags: bug, chat, profile-picture

I was in the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) today, when I noticed that one user's avatar changed color depending on how many posts in a row he had.

[image]

Other chat room members [confirmed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8063761#8063761) that the avatar looked strange.

[image: large]
[image: medium]
[image: small]
[image: tiny]

On my browser (Firefox 19.0), the 32x32 image looks out-of-place among the other sizes.

Comment: Maybe [someone is blackmailing Stack Exchange](http://www.edri.org/edrigram/number16/campina-blackmail)? ;-)

Comment: (For future reference: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uk8CF.png).)

Comment: @Arjan Dutch pudding poisoner?... You leave your country for a couple of years and miss all the interesting stuff. :)

Comment: @Bart, this was almost 10 years ago! Is that "a couple of years"? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Oh boy....that long...